# There is an error with my python program and I don't know what's wrong?

Tags: python

**This is the error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Computer Science\Python\Car Salesman Program Example.py", line 16, in <module>
    print ("The price of the car is now: "),(base * tax / 100)+(base*license /100)+ base + dealer_prep + destination_charge
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

**This is the program**

```
#Car salesman calculations program.
#The user enters the base price of the car and the program adds tax, license (which are both a percentage
#of the base price),dealer prep and destination charge. It then displays the final price. 

base = input("What is the base price of the car? ")

tax = 7

license = 4

dealer_prep = 500

destination_charge = 1000


print ("The price of the car is now: "),(base * tax / 100)+(base*license /100)+ base + dealer_prep + destination_charge
```

Comment: unsupported operand types gives you a clue

Comment: Format your code by putting 4 spaces before each line of it.  Then it will be clear which part is code and which is text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `base` is a string, so you can't do you calculations with `base` until you convert it to an integer:

```
base = int(input("What is the base price of the car? "))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating a **string**, "The price...", with an **integer**.  You need to convert your **integer** to a **string** with the str() function.

```
print ("The price of the car is now: "),
    str( (base * tax / 100)+(base*license /100)+ base + dealer_prep + destination_charge )
```